# Why does NavFn return a path that doesn't start from the robot location?

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, navfn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The path is the cyan line, and the robot is in the lower right corner. As you can see, the path doesn't start from where the robot is, resulting in move_base aborting the goal. The map isn't that big (1000x1000 px at 0.02 m/px) or complicated. Is there a limit to the path length that navfn returns?

[image: image description]

The move_base package version is 1.14.4, on kinetic. I'm using the navigation stack configuration that comes with the jackal_navigation package (0.6.3): https://github.com/jackal/jackal/tree/kinetic-devel/jackal_navigation

Platform: Ubuntu 16.0 (64-bit)

I modified a few parameters in the AMCL launch file for localization, but I don't think that is relevant here.
Here are my common (both global and local) costmap parameters:

```
map_type: costmap
origin_z: 0.0
z_resolution: 1
z_voxels: 2

obstacle_range: 6.0 
raytrace_range: 8.5 
always_send_full_costmap: True 

publish_voxel_map: false
transform_tolerance: 0.5
meter_scoring: true

footprint: [[-0.21, -0.165], [-0.21, 0.165], [0.21, 0.165], [0.21, -0.165]]
footprint_padding: 0.1

plugins:
- {name: obstacles_layer, type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"}
- {name: inflater_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

obstacles_layer:
  observation_sources: scan
  scan: {sensor_frame: front_laser, data_type: LaserScan, topic: front/scan, marking: true, clearing: true, min_obstacle_height: -2.0, max_obstacle_height: 2.0, obstacle_range: 6.0, raytrace_range: 8.5}

inflater_layer:
 inflation_radius: 1.75 
 cost_scaling_factor: 2.58
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333873/why-does-navfn-return-a-path-that-doesn%27t-start-from-the-robot-location?/) by [nightingale0131](https://answers.ros.org/users/46169/nightingale0131/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-09-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2019-09-25**:
Does this happen every path you attempt? Or just once?

**Comment by [nightingale0131](https://answers.ros.org/users/46169/nightingale0131/) on 2019-09-25**:
It seems to always happen whenever the path gets too long. If I set a goal close to the robot, there's no problem, but as soon as the shortest path exceeds some threshold it returns the non-valid path. I tested this using the move_base client and setting the goal point via rviz, and the same happens in either case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a [semi-arbitrary limit](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/melodic-devel/navfn/src/navfn.cpp#L298) of nx*ny/2 poses. I'm guessing you are seeing this problem whenever the path length is over 500,000 poses.

Solutions include

- Changing the number on the linked line
- Switch to another planner (global planner has a limit of [nx * ny * 2](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/melodic-devel/global_planner/src/planner_core.cpp#L290)

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2019-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nightingale0131](https://answers.ros.org/users/46169/nightingale0131/) on 2019-09-26**:
Oh, I see. I ended up switching to global planner and that solved the problem. Thank you for your help!